# How can I use the "avContent" API service in Multi mode?

Tags: api, camera, sony, add-on

How can I access the complete avContent API service in a Sony ActionCam AS-200V when operating the camera in WiFi mode? This avContent API responds to "getMethodTypes" with only the following methods when the camera is operating in WiFi mode. When operating the camera in direct attached mode this API shows all of its methods.

Results in WiFi mode:

```
{
    "results": [
    [
        "getMethodTypes",
        [
            "string"
        ],
        [
            "string",
            "string*",
            "string*",
            "string"
        ],
        "1.0"
    ],
    [
        "getVersions",
        [],
        [
            "string*"
        ],
            "1.0"
        ]
    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The HDR-AS200 supports single connection and multi connection as the way to connect to the other device for end-users, but for Camera Remote API beta, we only support single connection which is the one-to-one access of the camera and the other device.

So any functionality of the avContent service while in WiFi mode is not officially supported.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification Marlin. Is there any possibility of Sony opening up the avContent service in multi-connection mode as a "one off" feature for us? My client may be willing to pay for this capability.  Perhaps you could make it available as a private interface which could be enabled via accessControl or some other mechanism?